# jQuery UI Spinner - how to always display 3 decimal places

Tags: html, jquery-ui, web

I have an decimal input that is presented as a jQuery UI spinner. The spinner works perfectly but it does not display trailing 0.

I would like it to always display the .000 so that the user knows how many decimal points they can enter.

I have tried

```
$(".spinnerMaxTravel").spinner({
   min: 0,
   max: 4000,
   step: 0.001,
   numberFormat: "N3"                    
});
```

also to set it on initialize :

```
var num = 160.000;
var c = num.toFixed(3);
$('#spinner1').val(c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, try this.

```
    var num = 160.000;
    var c = num.toFixed(3);
    $('#spinner1').val(c+'.000');
    $("#spinner1").spinner({
        min: 0.000,
        max: 4000,
        step: 0.001,
        numberFormat: "N3",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($("#spinner1").val().indexOf(".") >= 0) {
            }
            else {
                $("#spinner1").val($(this).val() + '.000');
            }
        }
    });
```

Have fun